# Google cloud build "display name" for build steps

Tags: google-cloud-build

Is there a way to provide a "display name" for steps that would be shown in the build details of the build history?
What is currently display is the "name" field which is used to indicate the container image and is not a very useful way to convey meaning.

Comment: Will using [user-defined substitutuions](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) help in your case?

Comment: @EmilGi I think not because, as far as I understand, these substitutions are used as variables in the config file and do not control what is presented in the console.

Comment: I am pretty sure that they are preserved in the console. I understand that you want unique names for your steps, setting them in `id` field dynamically with user-defined variables shoudl suffice I think.

Comment: I tried using the id field with substitutions of the form `${_QQQ}` but it did not work. the strings were taken literally. (the same variables in other places were replaced with actual values)

Comment: It looks you are right and substitutions are not supported in 'id' field of step, I would say create a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or let me know and i can create it for you.

Answer (score 5):

The `id` field worked for me. I have a `cloudbuild.yaml` file as below:

```yaml
steps:
  - id: 'build-container-image'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'build'
      - '--network=cloudbuild'
      - '-t'
      - '${_REGION_NAME}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPO_NAME}/${_SERVICE_NAME}'
      - '.'

  - id: 'push-image-to-artifact-registry'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'push'
      - '${_REGION_NAME}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPO_NAME}/${_SERVICE_NAME}'

  - id: 'deploy-image-to-cloud-run'
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - '${_SERVICE_NAME}'
      - '--image'
      - '${_REGION_NAME}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPO_NAME}/${_SERVICE_NAME}'
      - '--region'
      - '${_REGION_NAME}'
      - '--platform'
      - 'managed'
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
substitutions:
  _REGION_NAME: us-west1
  _REPO_NAME: container-images
  _SERVICE_NAME: public-web-cloud-run
images:
  - '${_REGION_NAME}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPO_NAME}/${_SERVICE_NAME}'
```

This is what will be shown in the build details without the `id` field
[image: Build details without id field]

This is the build details after the `id` fields are added:
[image]

[Link to the `id` field in the official doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#id)

Answer (score 0):

Found out after some tests that the "id" field is presented 'as is' in the build details for each step and can be used as a field that is presented in the console. Note though that substitutions (i.e. `${QQQ}`) did not work for me in the 'id' field